# If text box empty, display alert box

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to coding and just trying to learn how to make a simple validation, to check if text box is filled in or not, but it never seems to work for me... This is my code:

Html:

```
Username:<br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname">
    <input type="submit" id="check" value="OK" onclick="check()">
```

Javascript:

```
//IF TEXT BOX EMPTY, DISPLAY ALERT MESSAGE.
function check(){
    var uname=document.getElementById(uname).value;
    if (uname==""){
        alert("Username is obligatory")
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you never call the function, have no HTML, and use `uname` before you assign it a value … maybe. Try providing a real [mcve]

Comment: Okey, but could you like add an example, that does the same thing? Thanks

Comment: `.getElementById("uname")` - the ID needs to be encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: It is working now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your markup and script:

You're missing quotes around uname `.getElementById("uname").value` and your function won't stop the form from submitting if there are validation issues.

Here is the fix for the immediate problem and a simple solution to keep the form from submitting when there are validation issues.

```
<script>
  function validateForm() {
      var uname=document.getElementById("uname").value;
      if (uname==""){
          alert("Username is obligatory");
          return false;
      }
  }
</script>
<form onSubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="uname">
  <input type="submit" id="check" value="OK">
</form>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iDEXsiXzVaADFG4qFQIX?p=preview)